# Como manter um arquivo local que está em conflito com o repositório?

Tags: android-studio, git

É possível, ao executar `git pull`, informar ao Git para não sobrescrever um  arquivo local que está em conflito com o repositório? Se sim, como fazê-lo?

O arquivo em questão já está no repositório. É um arquivo que foi criado pelo Android Studio, `app.iml` é o nome. Ao fazer um clone do projeto em outra máquina esse arquivo sofreu mudança e não quero *comitá-la*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [*stash*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) para "proteger" o arquivo. Assim pode voltar qualquer alteração que exista em arquivos locais. Claro que podem existir conflitos nessa volta que deverão ser resolvidos conforme a necessidade.

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Em alguns casos o basta colocar o arquivo no [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). O que estiver descrito ali não será considerado pelo Git.

Comment: Bigown, o arquivo já está no repositório. É um arquivo que foi criado pelo Android Studio, `app.iml` é nome. Na verdade não sei nem se deveria ter comitado. Ao fazer um clone do projeto em outra máquina esse arquivo sofreu mudança e não quero comitá-las.

Comment: è, então acredito que a solução do *stash* é a mais adequada.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `git stash`. O stash guarda os arquivos modificados e reverte a sua branch para `HEAD`, daí tu pode fazer o seu `git pull` normalmente.

Para criar o stash:
`git stash save <uma descrição>`

Para listar seus stash:
`git stash list`

Para recuperar seus arquivos
`git stash apply`

Para saber mais sobre o stash você pode digitar `git help stash` que a documentação será aberta no seu navegador.